# GMSAutocompleteViewController Localization

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api

I use GMSAutocompleteViewController in my application. And wondering that can i localize it (search bar text, error text shown in tableview, etc.) simply.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything to make this work. `GMSAutocompleteViewController` is fully localized.

Comment: Actually, results are localized but button with the text "Cancel" or textfield with placeholder "Search" etc, are not localized.

Comment: You might also need to add required languages to you app config for them to show up. See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH5-SW2

Comment: Search placeholder not localized